# how to resolve the problem with starting cmdb

Tags: mysql, django, cmdb

my softwares's version:
Django (1.11.13)
python 3.4.3
maraidb 10.5
when i use `python3 manage.py makemigrations` it occured an error with

```
File "/home/python34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/python34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 203, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'
```

how can i resolve the problem?

Comment: i might be python version issue

Comment: Should I update to python 3.5 or higher?

Comment: yes try to update your python version

Comment: Thank you so much i resolved the problem by your function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your python version from **python 3.4** to **python 3.5**